# python で 数値を桁別に取得するには

Tags: python

pythonで数値を桁別に取得したいです。
152という数字があったら、num[0]=1 num[1]=5 num[2]=2といった形にしたいです。

int(math.log10(num) + 1))で桁数を取得して、num[0]=152/100　…として求めていくのは考えつきますが、よりスマートにやる方法があったら知りたいです。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

スマートに、というより基本的な数値の10進変換をpythonで書くとこうなる言うことで。

```
num = []
n = 152
while n != 0:
  num.append(n % 10)
  n /= 10
num.reverse()

num
->[1, 5, 2]
```

一度文字列に変換するなんてのがありなら、こんな感じでも書けますね。

```
n = 152
num = map(int, str(n))
```

(追記)
前半のコードはn > 0, 後半のコードはn >= 0が動作条件ですね。整数は大前提としています。

Answer (score 2):

参考までに `generator` を使う方法などを。

```
def gen(n):
  if n < 10:
    yield n
  else:
    for m in gen(n/10):
      yield m
    yield n%10

>>> [int(i) for i in gen(123456)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> map(int, gen(944255603587320099))
[9, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 6, 0, 3, 5, 8, 7, 3, 2, 0, 0, 9, 9]
```